# Timestamp parsing in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql, simpledateformat

I'm trying to read a timestamp and reconstruct it in a different format as per my requirement, in Hive. But, I can't seem to get the month and date right. I suspect timestamp format to be incorrect but not sure where I'm going wrong.

**Query**

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("Sun Mar 28 19:51:10 GMT+05:30 2021", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY"), "HH:mm:ss dd-MM-YYYY-z")
```

**Output**

```
14:21:10 27-12-2021-UTC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class docs which is used under the hood of unix_timestamp and from_unixtime.

`y` - is a year ---this is what you need
`Y` - is week year ---this is what you used in a pattern

See also https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/MisusedWeekYear
And some explanation what is week year here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year

The week year for short is the year that the relevant week number belongs to.

Fixed:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("Sun Mar 28 19:51:10 GMT+05:30 2021", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"), "HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy-z")
```

Result:

```
14:21:10 28-03-2021-UTC
```

Comment: Thank you @leftjoin, I'm able to get the timestamp correctly now, after changing from YYYY to yyyy.

Comment: This document `https://help.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/date-and-time-format.html` google's top favorite is all wrong. I believe `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html`  should be the proper document to follow.