# HQL (HIVE) date_format adding an extra year after Dec 25th 2021

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql, simpledateformat

I am not sure if this is just on my local instance or if it is a fundamental problem but for me in hive date_format jumps a year after December 25th 2021.

```
Select date_format('2021-12-25','YYYY-MM-dd') as Correct2021
        ,date_format('2021-12-26','YYYY-MM-dd') as Wrong2022
        ,date_format(date_add(current_date,51),'YYYY-MM-dd') as Correct2021b
        ,date_format(date_add(current_date,52),'YYYY-MM-dd') as Wrong2022b
```

The code above for me returns

| correct2021 | wrong2022 | correct2021b | wrong2022b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-25 | 2022-12-26 | 2021-12-25 | 2022-12-26 |

If running on a different date then 11/4/2021 you would need to adjust the date adds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y pattern is a week year - a year which some week belongs to.

y - is what you need

```
Select date_format('2021-12-25','yyyy-MM-dd') as Correct2021
        ,date_format('2021-12-26','yyyy-MM-dd') as Wrong2022
        ,date_format(date_add(current_date,51),'yyyy-MM-dd') as Correct2021b
        ,date_format(date_add(current_date,52),'yyyy-MM-dd') as Wrong2022b
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69840917/2700344

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a java issue with 'Y' vs 'y'.

The issue is described here:
[Y returns 2012 while y returns 2011 in SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat)