# Date_format function in hive

Tags: sql, hive, date-format

I ran a basic select statement in hive expecting `20211227` but hive return `20221227`.

`select date_format('2021-12-27','YYYYMMdd')`

I ran the statement below and it gives me expected result `20211225`. Not sure, why hive behaves this way.

`select date_format('2021-12-25','YYYYMMdd')`

Comment: try this one select date_format('2021-12-27','dd-MM-YYYY'); if wont work then maybe check timezone settings.

Comment: Correct format should be `yyyyMMdd`. Hive follows java date format. Now why first sql isnt working, may be some issues with auto string to date conversion.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69840917/2700344

Answer (score 1):

hive uses Java simpledateformat. As per Java guide,

- y (lowercase) is year
- Y (uppercase) is 'week-based-year'

This difference will cause your code to work perfectly fine, except for when dealing with dates at the very end of some years.
So, when you use ('2021-12-27','YYYYMMdd'), yyyy will output 2021 but YYYY will output 2022. Because the week that the 27th of December falls in the first week of 2022.
`date_format('2021-12-25','YYYYMMdd')` is working because 25th Dec is not the first week of 2022.
Refer to below screenshot, you can see lowercase y is giving you correct result and uppercase is picking up year from first week of year which is 2022.

[image: example]

Please always use `yyyy` as per hive docs says.

Comment: Thanks, it worked